# Zero..One to One Relationship SQL

Tags: sql-server, many-to-many, one-to-one

I am trying to understand better 1-1 vs 1-0..1 relationship.

Let's say I have a **Car**, **SteeringWheel**, and **Sunroof**

- 1 **Car** must have 1 **SteeringWheel** and 1 **SteeringWheel** must belong to 1 **Car**; therefore this is 1:1 relationship
- 1 **Car** can have 0 or 1 **Sunroof** and a **Sanroof** must belong to 1 **Car**; therefore this is 0..1:1 relationship.

But in terms of entities, I am not sure how to implement 0..1:1 relationship.

Below is 1:1 relationship btw Car and Sunroof but it should be 1:0..1.

How to make it 1:0..1 relationship?

```
-------------- ONE TO ONE --------------
CAR                         SUNROOF
---------------             -------------
CarId PK    -1----+         SunroofId
Model             |         Diameter
Year              +--0..1-  CarId FK, UNIQUE
```

Comment: Your example is actually a 1:1 relationship. If you don't have a sunroof you simply don't have a row in the SUNROOF table.

Comment: OK, so the above is applicable to both 1:1 and 1:0..1 then?

Comment: Of course. Why wouldn't it work for that? You simply do a left join from Car to Sunroof. Are you sure that there will never be a case of a second sunroof in a vehicle? What about a t-top? They have two distinct pieces of glass. Some might be interchangeable but others are not and are sold as the driver side or passenger side.

Comment: Sean, the point is 1:0..1, not the Sunroof.  Sunroof is just example but assume, whatever it is it is only 1:0..1 relationship.  If you can think of better one fine but main question I have is how to make 1:0..1 relationship, that is all.  Dont worry about Sunroof and how many may a car have.  Assume, only one is possible or none in a car.  Thanks

Comment: Apparently you missed the important part of my previous comment. This part. "Of course. Why wouldn't it work for that? You simply do a left join from Car to Sunroof."

Comment: OK, so then my solution above for 1:1 also works for 1:0..1 is what you are saying

Comment: From a data perspective yes it works just fine for that. But if you are talking about entity framework then I am not any help.

Comment: OK, thanks.  Can you post as an answer so I can accept and thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a data perspective your design supports this correctly. To achieve the relationship beyond 1:1 you would just use a left join from Car to Sunroof. That way if there is no row for sunroof you get NULL. But the unique constraint on CarId prevents more than a single sunroof for a given car.

Answer (score 0):

I found this link that I think applies.

[Implementing one-to-zero-or-one relation in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7644156/implementing-one-to-zero-or-one-relation-in-sql-server)

Essentially, it says all 1-1 relationships are really 0..1-1.  In  that case the implementation would be the same.