# Should a 1-to-1 table relationship be employed here?

Tags: database, database-design, database-schema, one-to-one

I have the following columns for a simple request/action process between two users:

```
request_type
request_to
request_by
request_msg
request_time
```

and

```
action_type
action_by
action_msg
action_time
```

The top reply from [When we need to use 1-to-1 relationship in database design?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6352324/when-we-need-to-use-1-to-1-relationship-in-database-design) suggests my example does not fit any of the reasons accepted for partitioning here. However, I still find myself wondering whether these two sets of columns should belong in the same table because:

- the process is essentially two row inserts, but with the latter having to be applied using an update because the table contains both sets of columns
- each set cannot be updated, so two tables would lend itself to denying update privileges
- half the table is null fields while the action is pending
- while directly related, they still feel like two semantically different user actions

Thanks for any thoughts.

Comment: Just wait until there will be more than one action generated by a request...

Answer (score 0):

You could have two tables, one for requests and one for actions.

```
request
=======
request_id (primary key identity(1,1))
request_type (fk to type table)
request_to (fk to user table)
request_by (fk to user table)
request_msg 
request_time (default getdate())

action
======
action_id (primary key identity(1,1))
request_id (fk to request table)
action_type (fk to type table)
action_by (fk to user table)
action_msg 
action_time (default getdate())
```