# Error saving EF Core values with repository pattern

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have the following classes:

```cs
public class Equipment
{
     public const string TableName = "ew_equipamento";

     public int EquipmentId { get; set; }
     public int IdLote { get; private set; }
     public LTE_dp_to_dp _Lote { get; set; }
}

//Mapp:
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Equipment> builder)
{
    builder.ToTable(Equipamento.TableName);
    builder.HasKey(x => x.EquipmentId);

    builder.HasOne(x => x._Lote)
             .WithOne()
             .HasForeignKey<Equipment>(x => x.LotId);

    builder.HasOne(x => x._Model)
             .WithOne()
             .HasForeignKey<Equipment>(x=> x.IdEquipmentModel);
}

// -------

public class LTE_dp_to_dp
{
     public const string TableName = "ew_lte_cd_to_ft";

     public int IdLote { get; set; }
    
     public List<LTE_dp_to_dp_Equipamento> _LoteEquipamentos { get; set; }
}

//Mapp:
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<LTE_dp_to_dp> builder)
{
    builder.ToTable(LTE_dp_to_dp.TableName);
    builder.HasKey(x => x.IdLote);

    builder.HasMany(x => x._LoteEquipamentos)
             .WithOne(x=> x._Lote)
             .HasForeignKey(x => x.IdLote)
             .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
}

// -----
public class LTE_dp_to_dp_Equipamento
{
     public const string TableName = "ew_lte_cd_to_ft_equipamento";

     public int EquipmentLoteId { get; set; }
     public int EquipmentId { get; set; }
     public Equipment _Equipment { get; set; }

     public int IdLote { get; set; }
     public LTE_dp_to_dp _Lote { get; set; }
}

//Mapp:
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<LTE_dp_to_dp_Equipamento> builder)
{
    builder.ToTable(LTE_dp_to_dp_Equipamento.TableName);
    builder.HasKey(x => x.IdLoteEquipamento);

    builder.HasOne(x => x._Equipment)
             .WithOne()
             .HasForeignKey<LTE_dp_to_dp_Equipamento>(x => x.IdEquipamento);

    builder.HasOne(x => x._Lote)
             .WithMany(x=> x._LoteEquipamentos)
             .HasForeignKey(x => x.IdLote);
}
```

And I use the repositories pattern to search:

```cs
public async Task<LTE_dp_to_dp> GetAsync(int idLote)
         => await Query(x => x.IdLote == idLote)
             .Include(x => x._LoteEquipamentos.OrderBy(o => o.Caixa).ThenBy(o => o.IdLoteEquipamento))
             .ThenInclude(x => x._Equipment).ThenInclude(x => x._Model)
             .Include(x => x._LoteEquipamentos)
             .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

to update:

```cs
public void Update(TEntity model)
{
    DbSet.Attach(model);
    var entry = _context.Entry(model);
    entry.State = EntityState.Modified;
}
```

to save changes:

```cs
public async Task<bool> CommitAsync()
{
    int _changesNumber = await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    return _changesNumber > 0;
}
```

I search using `GetAsync`, cycle through the items, and change the equipment.

```
LTE_dp_to_dp lot = await _lteDpToDpRepository.GetAsync(idLote);`
```

Then, I go through the items:

```cs
foreach(var i in lot._LoteEquipamentos)
{
    i._Equipment.LotId = other....
    _equipamentoRepository.Update(i._Equipamento);
}

await _uow.CommitAsync();
```

but I get the following error:

> Unable to save changes because a circular dependency was detected in the data to be saved: 'Equipamento { 'IdEquipamento': 1571455 } [Modified] <-
> Index { 'ModelEquipmentId': 25 } Equipment { 'EquipmentId': 1571456 } [Modified] <-
> Index { 'ModelEquipmentId': 25 } Equipment { 'EquipmentId': 1571455 } [Modified]'.

I have already tried the following scenario:

```cs
foreach(var i in lot._LoteEquipamentos)
{
    i._Equipment.LotId = other....
    i._Equipment._Model = null;
    _equipamentoRepository.Update(i._Equipamento);
}
```

but I keep getting the same error...

EF Core 7..8

I expected update value from entity `Equipamento`, but I can't because of this error...

Comment: Have you check [Many-to-many relationships](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships/many-to-many)? You can refer to the model in the document to adjust your model.

Comment: Have you tried without repository pattern? Without attach? Just changing properties of object returned by EF. `Attach` and `Update` usually gives more pain than do the job.

Comment: So, i tried to change it

`builder.HasOne(x => x._Equipment).WithOne().HasForeignKey<LTE_dp_to_dp_Equipamento>(x => x.IdEquipamento);`
for that:

`builder.HasOne(x => x._Equipment).WithMany().HasForeignKey(x => x.IdEquipamento);`

And it worked successfully! but why?

Comment: Both sides of the many-to-many relationship are configured using the HasOne, WithMany, and HasForeignKey Fluent API methods. You can have a look at [EF Core Many To Many Relationship](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/co.nfiguration/many-to-many-relationship-configuration)

Comment: @Nowlights This code is deeply broken, just like all attempts to put a low-level CRUD class over the high-level Unit-of-Work that is DbContext. Try *removing* all this code and using DbContext as intended instead of trying to "improve" it. A DbContext already is a Unit-of-Work and multi-entity Repository. It's not a database connection or model. Like all ORMs, EF core tries to give the impression of working with in-memory objects, not tables and rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is with the one-to-one relationship you define between the `Equipment` and the `LTE_dp_to_dp` table.

A one-to-one relationship is made up from:

- One or more primary or alternate key properties on the principal entity.
- One or more foreign key properties on the dependent entity.

Simply put, you need to relate the identical columns. Please see [Which way should a Foreign Key go in a one to one relationship?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8214973/which-way-should-a-foreign-key-go-in-a-one-to-one-relationship) for more information.

That said, to resolve the issue, remove the property `public int LoteId { get; set; }` from Equipment class and relate their primary keys as follows:

Equipment model:

```
public class Equipment
{
    public const string TableName = "ew_equipamento";
    public int EquipmentId { get; set; }
    //public int LoteId { get; set; } //TODO Remove
    public LTE_dp_to_dp _Lote { get; set; }
}
```

LTE_dp_to_dp model:

```
public class LTE_dp_to_dp
{
    public const string TableName = "ew_lte_cd_to_ft";
    public int LoteId { get; set; }
    public Equipment _Equipment { get; set; } //TODO Add
    public List<LTE_dp_to_dp_Equipamento> _LoteEquipamentos { get; set; }
}
```

LTE_dp_to_dp_Equipamento model:

```
public class LTE_dp_to_dp_Equipamento
{
    public const string TableName = "ew_lte_cd_to_ft_equipamento";
    public int EquipmentLoteId { get; set; }
    //public int EquipmentId { get; set; } //TODO Remove
    //public Equipment _Equipment { get; set; } //TODO Remove
    public int LoteId { get; set; }
    public LTE_dp_to_dp _Lote { get; set; }
}
```

### Configuration Mapping

Equipment:

```
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Equipment> builder)
{
    builder.ToTable(Equipment.TableName);
    builder.HasKey(x => x.EquipmentId);
    // Define a 1:1 relationship.
    // You can define here or on the LTE_dp_to_dp config, but NOT on both!
    builder.HasOne(x => x._Lote)
        .WithOne(x => x._Equipment)
        .HasForeignKey<LTE_dp_to_dp>(x => x.LoteId);
}
```

LTE_dp_to_dp:

```
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<LTE_dp_to_dp> builder)
{
    builder.ToTable(LTE_dp_to_dp.TableName);
    builder.HasKey(x => x.LoteId);
}
```

LTE_dp_to_dp_Equipamento :

```
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<LTE_dp_to_dp_Equipamento> builder)
{
    builder.ToTable(LTE_dp_to_dp_Equipamento.TableName);
    builder.HasKey(x => x.EquipmentLoteId);
    // Define a 1:many relationship.
    builder.HasOne(x => x._Lote)
        .WithMany(x=> x._LoteEquipamentos)
        .HasForeignKey(x => x.LoteId)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
}
```

You **don't need** to define a one-to-one relationship between the `LTE_dp_to_dp_Equipamento` and the `Equipment` table as you can always access using the `LTE_dp_to_dp` table. If you feel that you need to, then you may need to revise your data structure otherwise it is simply a bad design.

After migration your table structure should look as follows:

[image: One-To-One Relationship]

Comment: Just learnt this. Awesome