# How to design one business model to multiple tables?

Tags: database, database-design, normalization, one-to-one

What is the best practice to design one business model into a multiple tables using one to one relationship?
Lets say I Have the following diagram;
[image: Demo Diagram]

Both tables are representing ONE business object/entity which is the Person. For table `PersonNationalId` is it a best practice is to

1. Add addition column `PersonNationalId` to be the primary key
2. Remove  the unique key and mark the `PersonId` as the Primary key? (I recommend this solution)
3. It's good like that with the unique key and we don't have to add any primary keys?

I'm not considering breaking the business to two/multiple tables because I update each table from a different screen in my system and I want to track the changes (through `CreatedBy` and `CreatedDate` columns in each table)

What is the best practice from the previous choices/solutions? if you any additional solution I will be happy to know it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Documents expire, and when they do, new ones are issued with a new number. They also get lost, stolen ...
So, start with something like ...

[image]

Comment: Actually your answer wasn't clear but I knew the answer from your previous question :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1722741/defining-a-one-to-one-relationship-in-sql-server/1723519#1723519 so thanks you've helped me :)

Answer (score 1):

If you really need 1:1 then both PKs would be identical and you'd have a circular FKs between them. Does you DBMS support **deferred** constraints, which are necessary to "break" the cycle and allow insertion of new data?

---

That being said, this case doesn't look like 1:1 to me. It looks like 1:N, as Damir [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10798912/533120).

Comment: This example wasn't my case but I was trying to give a similar example